# Create a loop that puts a word from the list into the link

Tags: python, list, loops

I have created a sample list of list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]. I would like to create a new list with a loop, in which the items from list1 would be saved, connected with an https link. In list2, the items in the list would look like this: "https://www.google.com/a", "https://www.google.com/b" .... How to do is in python3?

Comment: Please provide your code so we can see what your "https link" actually is in terms of Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
base_url = 'https://www.google.com/'
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = [f"{base_url}{item}" for item in list1]
```